# How to solve Android Fatal signal in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

First, I create a new project.

after that, I Click on the TextFormField (in case you show the TextFormField  the app will crash, in case you keep it commented the app will works).

I have tried the demo and it crashed on Samsung emulator

Please let me know if you now can reproduce the error thanks :)

**The code example:**

```
import 'package:eommerce_p/view/component_widgets/custom_text.dart';
import  'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignInScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<SignInScreen> createState() => _SignInScreenState();
}

class _SignInScreenState extends State<SignInScreen> {
  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Login In')
      ),
      body: Column(
      children: [
        CustomText(
            text: "Welcome Sign In",
            color : Colors.black,
            size : 26,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        CustomText(
          text: "Sign in with your email and password  \nor continue with social media",
          color : Colors.grey,
          maxLines: 2,
          size: 14,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Email",
              hintText: "Please entrer your email"
            ),
   ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
      ],
    )
    );
  }

}
```

***this is the output:***

```
Launching lib\main.dart on A5010 in debug mode...
Parameter format not correct -
?  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:58740/foWPT2EqIbU=/ws
F/libc    ( 3084): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 3198 (1.raster)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'OnePlus/OnePlus/A5010:5.1.1/20171130.376229:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
pid: 3084, tid: 3198, name: 1.raster  >>> com.krim.eommerce_p <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
    eax b3f75000  ebx 9fc8e388  ecx 00000000  edx b3ed300c
    esi b3ed3068  edi 00000000
    xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 0000003b  xss 0000007b
    eip 9f6ae059  ebp 9dd7b088  esp 9dd7b020  flags 00210296
backtrace:
    #00 pc 003b2059  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #01 pc 003ba2f6  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #02 pc 003b8ffd  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #03 pc 002e8a7b  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #04 pc 002e6f08  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #05 pc 003592e9  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #06 pc 00359212  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #07 pc 0036caac  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #08 pc 0036c982  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #09 pc 002dafa2  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #10 pc 002dabbc  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #11 pc 002db3ce  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #12 pc 002d530c  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #13 pc 001493f5  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #14 pc 001493bb  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #15 pc 00149376  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #16 pc 005695cd  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #17 pc 005698f9  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #18 pc 0002edbc  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #19 pc 00443a8b  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #20 pc 00443af8  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #21 pc 00443ac0  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #22 pc 004606ec  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #23 pc 0045ed1b  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #24 pc 0045fa8b  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #25 pc 00460e8e  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #26 pc 000330c5  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #27 pc 0045f231  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #28 pc 0045eefb  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #29 pc 004708b0  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #30 pc 0002ca59  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #31 pc 00030bad  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #32 pc 00030abe  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #33 pc 000380ca  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #34 pc 000380f8  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #35 pc 000198b0  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::SimpleLooperCallback::handleEvent(int, int, void*)+32)
    #36 pc 0001ba42  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+690)
    #37 pc 0001bc57  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+55)
    #38 pc 0000ba7c  /system/lib/libandroid.so (ALooper_pollOnce+92)
    #39 pc 0003800d  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #40 pc 00030a6c  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #41 pc 00030594  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #42 pc 00035d62  /data/app/com.krim.eommerce_p-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #43 pc 000212b8  /system/lib/libc.so
    #44 pc 0001c639  /system/lib/libc.so
    #45 pc 00013206  /system/lib/libc.so
Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_07
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import 'package:eommerce_p/view/component_widgets/custom_text.dart';
import  'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignInScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<SignInScreen> createState() => _SignInScreenState();
}

class _SignInScreenState extends State<SignInScreen> {
  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Login In')
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(child:Column(
      children: [
        CustomText(
            text: "Welcome Sign In",
            color : Colors.black,
            size : 26,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        CustomText(
          text: "Sign in with your email and password  \nor continue with social media",
          color : Colors.grey,
          maxLines: 2,
          size: 14,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
      
        SizedBox(
         height: 100 // try to estimate the height of the contents below. You can't add a textfield the way you did. You need to give estimated height
        child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Email",
              hintText: "Please entrer your email"
            ),
   ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      ),
    )
      ],
    )
    )
    );
  }

}
```

**NOTE**: If it still does not work. You can try on a real device

Comment: Hi ,the problem is when I use textFormField in my application, the application crash and exit it ,I  trayed with different projects, but the same problem, I want to know what is the problem exactly using the output message above ?